# How can i integrate Xpertdoc with Microsoft flows?

Tags: dynamics-crm, integration, power-automate

I have a task to integrate Xpertdoc with Microsoft flows for sending emails. I know we can use smart flows for this purpose which we have integrated with our Dynamics CRM but we need to send out emails for customers other than CRM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the Smart Flows development team so my answer is from that perspective.

You can probably solve this with Smart Flows, but we'll need to know how and where these contacts are stored. I suggest you send us a mail (we're still using info@xperido.com) so we can talk about this more in detail.